# Set strapi permission to specific collection data

Tags: strapi

I am planning in developing a large structure for a client and I am looking into using Strapi to manage the content and the APIs.

Before even digging  deeper I would like to ask if anyone know if there is an existing plugin to set limitations to the collections data.

For example, I create a collection  called restaurant where I am going to have 1 field: name. Then I create 2 restaurants named "The Optimist" & "The Negative"

After, I create 2 more user for my back end: Maria & Julia.

Is there any existing way to set Maria to only be able to edit "The optimist" & Julia to only edit "The Negative"?

Answer (score 3):

##### Explaination

Well there is a way to limit users from performing specific actions on the entire collection directly out of the box, but limiting to specific entries needs customization in controller.

I would recommend you to go through [Users, Roles & Permissions](https://docs.strapi.io/user-docs/latest/users-roles-permissions/introduction-to-users-roles-permissions.html) guide from the `Strapiv4` documentation for better understanding.
Attaching a snapshot below you give you a brief idea. As you can see, generic actions like create, update, delete etc. can be permitted only to specific roles, which in turn can be assigned to the users of your choice.

##### # Image showing permissions being assigned to a role

[image]

##### # Image showing role being assigned to a user

[image]

##### Solution

Coming to your question on limiting users to specific entries, you can easily achieve this by writing custom code that checks for the entry id and the role that's trying to update the restaurant. Check the snippet below:

```js
// src/api/resto/controllers/resto.js

"use strict";

/**
 *  resto controller
 */

const { createCoreController } = require("@strapi/strapi").factories;

module.exports = createCoreController("api::resto.resto", ({ strapi }) => ({
  async update(ctx) {
    const { id } = ctx.params;
    const { role } = ctx.state.user;
    // if you don't want to hard code the ids, you can do a findOne for the id and do a check on the resto name. 
    // Assuming id 4 corresponds to entry "The optimist"
    // Assuming id 5 corresponds to entry "The Negative"
    if ((id === 4 && role.name !== "Role Maria") || (id === 5 && role.name !== "Role Julia")) {
      return ctx.badRequest("You are not allowed to update this entry", {
        id: id,
        role: role.name,
      });
    } 
  
    const entity = await strapi
      .service("api::resto.resto")
      .update(id, { data: ctx.request.body });

    const response = await super.findOne(ctx);
    // const sanitizedEntity = await this.sanitizeOutput(response, ctx);
    // return this.transformResponse(sanitizedEntity);
    return response;
  },
}));
```

Comment: interesting! let me try this out